# Doxverilog - not patching when configuring

Tags: doxygen

I have doxygen 1.8.5 and Doxverilog (for doxygen 1.7.0). Following the instructions quoted below I get messages saying that patches have previously been applied. Then some of the HUNKs fail.

If I proceed anyway and set up the verilog.cfg, running doxygen with this cfg produces

"Warning: ignoring unsupported tag `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VERILOG =' at line 35, file verilog.cfg"
Then blank output.

The instructions I'm using to setup doxverilog are:

---

```
install the doxygen-1.7.0 sources

1. copy the Verilog files verilogparser.y verlogscanner.l and the source files to the doxygen-1.7.0\src directory

2. copy the patch file verilog.patch to directory doxygen-1.7.0

3. open a shell in the doxygen-1.7.0 directory

3.1 configure doxygen
    sh configure

3.2  make  patch  # patch -p1 < verilog.patch

4 compile  the source files
  make all

5 If the compilation was successful create a doxygen configuration file with  # doxygen -s -g verilog.cfg
  In the configuration file you should see the option OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VERILOG. 
  The file patterns for the Verilog parser  are *.v and *.V
```

Comment: Quite a lot has changed since the 1.7.0 version and has the verilog patch been updated for these changes? I'm thinking a.o. about the way the config.xml is used.

Comment: I think you are correct - I need a newer version of doxverilog. Unfortunately the later versions all seem to be corrupt. Is there a way of getting an older (1.7.0) version of Doxygen?

Comment: I'm advising against going for the 1.7.0 version of doxygen as it is quite old and as written before a lot has changed. It is possible to get older versions see e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/ for versions down to 1.7.1  or see ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/ for an even more complete set. Best would be that the doxyverilog got updated to the current version.